# Pythagorean Theorem to check whether a cell is inside the radius

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have the **dimensions** of a matrix and a **given cell** with **radius**.

So let's take a look at this example:

[image: Matrix]

The matrix has **5 rows** and **6 columns**. We are given the cell **(2, 3)** with **radius 2**. It has an impact, and it destroys all of the items in a certain radius (the **impact cell** is shaded **black** and the **other cells** within the radius are shaded **grey**). I found that I could use the **Pythagorean Theorem** to check whether a cell is inside the radius:

```
if (Math.Pow(targetRow - row, 2) + Math.Pow(targetColumn - col, 2) <= radius * radius)
{
    matrix[row, col] = 1; 
}
```

I don't understand why it works, and I would be very grateful if you could explain it to me. I tried to debug, but I still don't get it.

Comment: @UK_Dev, sorry but I didn't understand you. I am 8th grade and it's hard for me to understand what you've written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, because you can think of the radius of a circle as of the hypotenuse of a right triangle and, if the center of the circle is at the origin `(0, 0)` of the coordinate system, the x- and y-coordinates are the other two sides (the catheti).

[image]

Now let's call the two catheti `a` and `b` and the hypotenuse `c`. Then we following equation is true:

c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>       (the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem))

In your case `a` and `b` are `targetRow - row` and `targetColumn - col` and `c` is `radius`.

I don't know how `Math.Pow` is implemented, but it works on doubles and is rather expensive. Do the math with integers.

```
int dr = targetRow - row;
int dc = targetColumn - col;
if (dr * dr + dc * dc <= radius * radius)
{
    matrix[row, col] = 1; 
}
```

---

A side note: The distance calculated with the Pythagorean theorem is the **Euclidean distance**:

### d<sub>Euclidean</sub> = √(dx<sup>2</sup> + dy<sup>2</sup>)

It is appropriate for your problem. But there are other ways of defining the distance. Especially in a matrix.

A taxi in Manhattan first drives along the north-south axis, then makes a right angle turn and drives along the east-west axis to reach a target. This is **Taxicab geometry**. The shortest possible drive is called the **Manhattan distance**:

### d<sub>Manhattan</sub> = |dx| + |dy|

On a chessboard kings and queens can move horizontally, vertically and along diagonals. The minimum distance under these circumstances is called **Chebyshev distance** or **Chess distance**

### d<sub>Chebyshev</sub> = max(|dx|, |dy|)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what there is more to explain than the Pythagorean theorem just the equation for a circle `x^2 +y^2 = r^2`.

Thus in looping you're evaluating whether the evaluated point falls inside the circle.

[image: Pythagorean Theorem in Circles]

Check if this helps: [Pythagorean Theorem in Circles](https://cetking.com/pythagorean-theorem-circles/)